# VS Code won't open existing files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just updated to VS Code 1.11.2 on Windows 8.1 and when I open existing projects, files are shown in the explorer but an attempt to open any of them just shows a blank window with a blue "progress" bar endlessly scrolling across the top of the window. Creating and editing new files works. Any ideas?

[image: blank window with progress bar]

In the console of the Developer Tools is the following:

```
[uncaught exception]: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
[uncaught exception]: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'd:\Dev\AngularJS2\translation-editor\app\editor\translation-editor.component.html'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'd:\Dev\AngularJS2\translation-editor\app\editor\translation-editor.component.html'
    at Error (native)
Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'd:\Dev\AngularJS2\translation-editor\app\editor\translation-editor.component.html'
Workbench did not finish loading in 10 seconds, that might be a problem that should be reported.
```

Comment: have you tried closing vs code app and restart?

Comment: Yes. I've actually uninstalled and re-installed the app and extensions. I have also checked that the files are not read-only, etc.